# how to find the full name of athlete in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say this is my data frame:

```
country     Edition   sports       Athletes        Medal    Firstname   Score
Germany     1990    Aquatics  HAJOS, Alfred          gold     Alfred     3
Germany     1990    Aquatics  HIRSCHMANN, Otto       silver   Otto       2
Germany     1990    Aquatics  DRIVAS, Dimitrios      silver   Dimitrios  2
US          2008    Athletics MALOKINIS, Ioannis     gold     Ioannis    1
US          2008    Athletics HAJOS, Alfred          silver   Alfred     2
US          2009    Athletics CHASAPIS, Spiridon     gold     Spiridon   3
France      2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold     Efstathios 3
France      2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold     Efstathios 3
France      2010    golf      HAJOS, Alfred          Bronze   Alfred     1
France      2011    golf      ANDREOU, Joannis       silver   Joannis    2
Spain       2011    golf      BURKE, Thomas          gold     Thomas     3
```

I am trying to find out which Athlete's first name has the largest sum of scores?
I have tried the following:

`df.groupby ( 'Firstname' )[Score ].sum().idxmax()`

This returns the first name of the Athlete but I want to display the full name of Athlete can anyone  help me in this?

for example : I am getting 'Otto' as output but i want to display HIRSCHMANN, Otto as output!

Note: what I have noticed in my original data set when I groupby ( 'Athlete') the answer is different.

Comment: `df[df.groupby ( 'Firstname' )[Score ].sum().idxmax() ]`?

Comment: your solution will only give me the first name from column Firstname but i want to display the full name of the athlete from column athletes.

Answer (score 0):

`idxmax` will only give you the index of the *first* row with maximal value. If multiple `Firstname` share the max score, it will find to find them.

Try this instead:

```
sum_score = df.groupby ('Firstname')['Score'].sum()
max_score = sum_score.max()
names = sum_score[sum_score == max_score].index

df[df['Firstname'].isin(names)]
```

Comment: your solution is displaying the entire data frame i just want to display single output that is name of the athlete

Comment: Select the columns you want from that frame: `df[df['Firstname'].isin(names)]['Athletes']`